# One or more invalid names were detected in this workbook. Those invalid names have been changed to #REF

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openoffice-calc

tried to refer value from cell ('CD') to a particular cell, works fine in OpenOffice but not works for ms excel

```
for () {
        Name houseHoldRelationNamedCell = workbook.createName();
                houseHoldRelationNamedCell.setNameName("name"+ loopCounter);
        houseHoldRelationNamedCell.setRefersToFormula("$"+ CellReference.convertNumToColString(hiddenCellColumn) +"$1");

    DVConstraint constraintHouseholdRltn = DVConstraint.createFormulaListConstraint("name"+ beneficiaryRelationVO.getId());
    CellRangeAddressList addressListHouseholdRltn = new CellRangeAddressList(row, totalRows, column-1, column-1);
    HSSFDataValidation validationHouseholdRltn = new HSSFDataValidation(addressListHouseholdRltn, constraintHouseholdRltn);
    validationHouseholdRltn.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
    sheet.addValidationData(validationHouseholdRltn);
loopCounter++;
}
```

Excel Error : "One or more invalid names were detected in this workbook. Those invalid names have been changed to #REF!"

In ms excel  'Formulas' -> 'Name Manager' shows valid name+'loopCounter value'  but reference value as '=#NA!'

Comment: Which MS EXcell version??

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode ms excel 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking your code.I have found that while you are referring the cell you are using only `$CD1$`(CD is the sample cell address without sheetname).

When the name is Global (no sheet reference), the "current" sheet (current to the reference to the name) is assumed in OpenOffice Org. MS Excel 2007+ doesn't do this. It requires a sheet reference `(Sheet1!name)`.

Your code should be like this.

```
houseHoldRelationNamedCell.setRefersToFormula("'sheetname'!$"+ CellReference.convertNumToColString(hiddenCellColumn) +"$1");
```